# Is this good way to use php in html page

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

```
<?php
require_once('dbcon.php');
$query = "select * from indexpage";
$query2= "SELECT * FROM `blogintro`   ORDER BY `id` DESC;";
$query3= "SELECT * FROM `indexjob`   ORDER BY `id` DESC;";
$query4= "SELECT * FROM `dsintro`   ORDER BY `id` DESC;";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$query2);
$result3 = mysqli_query($con,$query3);
$result4 = mysqli_query($con,$query4);
?>
```

I am working on a website name codeavenues.com and i am retrieving most of the content from database using php at home page

i have used more than one query in single html page and now i have a doubt is it good way to use php. Because it give some issue like loading time.

Unable to test in google adsense platform. That's why i ask this question

```
<div class=row>
<?php
                        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2))
                        {
                            ?>
<div class="alert alert-primary alert-box ant-card" role=alert>
<a href=<?php echo ($row['link']); ?>>
<h6><span class="spinner-grow text-success" role=status style=width:1rem;height:1rem></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<?php echo $row['heading']; ?></h6>
<p> <?php echo $row['text']; ?><a href=<?php echo ($row['link']); ?>>Read More</a></p>
</a>
<br><br>
<p><i class="fa fa-rss" aria-hidden=true></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=# class=small> <?php echo $row['tag1']; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=# class=small> <?php echo $row['tag2']; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=# class=small> <?php echo $row['tag3']; ?></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=# class=small> <?php echo $row['tag4']; ?></a></p>
</div>
<?php
                        }?>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't use PHP ina normal HTML file. PHP only works in PHP files. But it is completely normal that you have HTML Markups in a PHP file.

Answer (score 1):

I should preface by stating that you can't use PHP in an HTML file (.html/.htm), you use HTML with PHP in a PHP file (.php). HTML is built into PHP, but PHP is not built into HTML. The primary reason of this is that HTML is frontend, and PHP is backend. PHP will serve the HTML to the client, and run the PHP scripts in the backend, and as such, HTML can't run PHP, since it would be running it in the frontend.

If we're simply analyzing the PHP code you have, I would say that your code is fine, other than one small aspect- prepared statements. Prepared statements increase performance, speed, and security. Without them, your code is highly vulnerable to SQL injection.

```
<?php
require_once('dbcon.php');

// Prepare the SQL statements
$stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM `indexpage`");
$stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM `blogintro` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$stmt3 = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM `indexjob` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$stmt4 = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM `dsintro` ORDER BY `id` DESC");

// Execute the prepared statements
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt3);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt4);

// Bind the results of the executed statements
$result1 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt1);
$result2 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt2);
$result3 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt3);
$result4 = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt4);

// Close the prepared statements
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt1);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt2);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt3);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt4);
?>
```

Finally, on the question of the multiple queries, it's very common to use multiple queries, and it shouldn't affect the loading time of the page very much. That said, I will reiterate that prepared statements will help with the load time of the page.

Answer (score -3):

It is absolutely normal to have many queries in one php page. You can use html in php pages. Load time is not dependant on the number of mysql queries but how each query performs while processing data. Also try using more prepared sql statements for optimized performance.

Comment: the number SQL queries have an impact on the load times. Not as high but they do. Prepared SQL statements are mandatory not for optimization performances but for security reasons (SQL injections).

Comment: While prepared statements are primarily used for enhanced security, they reduce parsing overhead and reduce network traffic by sending only the parameters for execution. You do get optimzed performance.